# Removing an item from a validation list when it has been selected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a revision session [register system]  [simple test version here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G-vytiaRfVnd20SxIHJSL84rdRzmnyXB8FJl-gJtvr8/edit?usp=sharing) for use in a school. 
There is a column of unallocated students and a column of allocated students. This is used as the source for validation drop down list boxes.

Teachers can select a student for their register from a drop down list.
When a student has been selected, they become unavailable to other teachers by removing them from the  and their name is added to the allocated list.

If a teacher deletes a student from their list, the student will be moved back to the unallocated column, allowing another teacher to select him/her.

I've made some progress, and can remove a student from the unallocated list and add them to the allocated list.

I am struggling with making deallocation work.

If a teacher deletes a student from their list, this is what I think should happen:

1- make a flattened array from the grid of all students selected by all teachers.
2- make an array of all students in the allocated column.

3- the student not in the array from the grid of all teachers but in the list of allocated students is the one that has just been deleted, remove this student from allocated and add them back to the unallocated column.

The function is fired by an onedit trigger event.
For some reason, the function I have used to flatten the array does not work, even though logging output suggests it should.

My code is below, (1)can anyone see what I've done wrong? (2)see a better way of doing what I am trying to accomplish? (my way seems very long winded)

```
function flatten(arrayOfArrays)
{
  Logger.log("concat");   
  var array =  [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
  return array;
}

function search(searchString) //returns array row index
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
    var column =11; //column Index   
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
    var searchResult = -1;
    for (var row = 1; row < columnValues.length; row ++)
    {
      if (columnValues[row][0]==searchString)
      {
        searchResult = row;
      }
    }

    return searchResult;
}

function cellEdited(e)
{

}
function studentAllocated(e) 
{
  var range = e.range
  var name = range.getValue();
  var row = search(name) +1;
  //remove name from to allocate column
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("K"+row);
  cell.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
}

function studentDeallocated() 
{
  Logger.log("SDeallocated2");
  //get all the names in the range of teachers
  //compare with all the names in the assigned col
  //the name that is not in the range of teachers but is in assigned col is the name that must be returned
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var assigned = sheet.getRange(2,12,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValues();//get all teachers registers
  Logger.log(values);
  var name = ""
  Logger.log(flatten(assigned))
  var nassigned = flatten(assigned);
  var nvalues = flatten(values);
  Logger.log("flat");
  Loggger.log(nassigned);

  var name = "";

  for (var v=0; v< values.length; v++)
  {
    var found = false;
    for (var a=0; a< assigned.length; a++)
    {
      Logger.log("loop iter: "+ a);
      if(values[v]==assigned[a])
      {
        Logger.log("found name:" +values[v] );
        found == true;
      }
    }
    if (found == false);
    name = values[v];
    break;

  //add name back to to allocate col
  sheet.getRange(1, 11, sheet.getLastRow()).setValue("name");
  }
}


function search(searchString) //returns array row index
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
    var column =11; //column Index   
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
    var searchResult = -1;
    for (var row = 1; row < columnValues.length; row ++)
    {
      if (columnValues[row][0]==searchString)
      {
        searchResult = row;
      }
    }

    return searchResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with a validation error for all assigned cells, you can do it without any script like this:

1. In column A:A list all students.
2. In cell B1 enter a formula `=filter(A:A,countif(C:C,A:A)=0)`. Column B will contain all unassigned students.
3. In column C:C have all assignments referenced from teachers' cells.
4. In teachers' cells add a list validation based on B:B range.

If you do not want this error you can still make separate validation lists for each teacher, including his student along with all unassigned students.

An example is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EO2a9rY6fh7FZY8-7TwFTP0t3PQhhPU8TSYxyHHJuEM/edit?usp=sharing). Both approaches are in separate sheets.

Edit: I just noticed that each teacher should have a list of students. In such a case you would need to treat each teacher's list entry as a separate 'teacher'. The approach without validation error would need to maintain a separate validation list for each teacher's list entry (e.g. 3 teachers * 5 entries * 9 students will make 135 validation list entries).

Comment: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nZMivNhnLMMItwtI5V2JcDhQVO4tZu62Z3rR74RJbRo/edit?usp=sharing]Thanks, I've just done it. That's brilliant. Coupled with some simple appscripts to add some other features like email reminders and protecting a teachers register from being changed by other teachers this is perfect :-)